# FB meta: ogurl bad redirect

Tags: html, facebook, meta

I have a problem with meta og:url
Link to debuger [a link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fadvicerest.com%2Findex-advice-27.html)!

It's looking all right, but it's not.
If I click the url (example Canonical URL), it redirects me to a UK address. I dont know what it is, I was trying to fix it but with fail. Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your document contains

```
<meta property="og:url"
  content="http://advicerest.com/index?goto=advice&advice=27.html" />
```

but that URL just results in a 404 Not Found.

Comment: Sorry for this i only what to fix the problem, and i remove rewriterule and now its: http://advicerest.com/index.php?goto=advice&advice=27

Comment: hmm in ie redirect me to good site but i get response "Cant show site", when i refresh site its work. I dont know what isn't